# Getting ListView scroll position

Tags: nativescript

Is possible to get ListView Y scroll position?

I can't find any info about listview scroll positions. in docs. I just found that I can get position only in ScrollView by:

```
scrollView.scrollToVerticalOffset
```

Comment: You are use ListView / RadListView?

Comment: @Manoj ListView